# Match characters by their place in Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to match numeric characters by their place within a string. For example, in the string `"1234567"`, I would like to select the second through the fourth characters: `"234"`. `"D9873Y.31"` should also turn up `"987"`. Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need a regex, you can just use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
s = '1234567'
s[1..3]  #=> "234"

s = 'D9873Y.31'
s[1..3]  #=> "987"
```

Comment: Brilliant -- that's simple and makes so much sense. Thanks! Casimir's solution also works well -- but you are correct that there is no need for a regex in this case.

Comment: Just for the reference of anyone learning this (I'm teaching myself): I also used what you said towards doing the same function, but for the same items in an array instead of as separate strings. For that, I used `choppedArray =  myArray.map{|chop| chop[1..3]}`. This produces the same output, but for an array.

Comment: @CodeBiker It might be better to name `chop` as `string` or something. I look at it and I can’t not think of [`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chop)—plus it isn’t really anything that’s “chopped”, more something that’s *about to be* chopped—but actually sliced because chop means something else.

Comment: Good point, it's the same name as the actual method. Better to use something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for this, and, patterns are flexible enough to write them several different ways. I try to keep them very simple, because they can become maintenance nightmares due to their cryptic nature:

```
"1234567"[/^.(.{3})/, 1]
=> "234"
"D9873Y.31"[/^.(.{3})/, 1]
=> "987"

"1234567".match(/^.(.{3})/)[1]
=> "234"
"D9873Y.31".match(/^.(.{3})/)[1]
=> "987"
```

You can also take advantage of [named-captures](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E):

```
/^.(?<chars2_4>.{3})/ =~ "1234567"
chars2_4
=> "234"

/^.(?<chars2_4>.{3})/ =~ "D9873Y.31"
chars2_4
=> "987"
```

All that's nice, but it's really important to dig in and learn them well, because, done wrong, you can grab the wrong data, or worse, really slow your script by making the regex engine work very hard to do something simple.

For instance, I used `^` above. `^` matches the start of a line, which is the start of a string and the character immediately following a new-line. That's OK for a short string, but long strings, especially with embedded new-lines can slow down the engine. Instead you might want to use `\A`. The same situation applies to using `$` or `\Z` or `\z`. This is from the Regexp documentation section for "Anchors":

- `^` - Matches beginning of line
- `$` - Matches end of line
- `\A` - Matches beginning of string.
- `\Z` - Matches end of string. If string ends with a newline, it matches just before newline
- `\z` - Matches end of string

And all that is why you sometimes want to avoid using a regexp and instead use a substring such as @AndrewMarshall recommended.

Here's another reason why the simple substring way is preferable:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm(13) do |b|
  b.report('string index') { N.times {
    "1234567"[1..3]
    "D9873Y.31"[1..3]
  } }

  b.report('regex index') { N.times {
    "1234567"[/^.(.{3})/, 1]
    "D9873Y.31"[/^.(.{3})/, 1]
  } }

  b.report('match') { N.times {
    "1234567".match(/^.(.{3})/)[1]
    "D9873Y.31".match(/^.(.{3})/)[1]
  } }

  b.report('named capture') { N.times {
    /^.(?<chars2_4>.{3})/ =~ "1234567"
    /^.(?<chars2_4>.{3})/ =~ "D9873Y.31"
  } }

  b.report('look behind') { N.times {
    "1234567"[/(?<=^.{2}).{3}/, 1]
    "D9873Y.31"[/(?<=^.{2}).{3}/, 1]
  } }
end
```

Which returns:

```
                    user     system      total        real
string index    0.730000   0.000000   0.730000 (  0.727323)
regex index     1.370000   0.000000   1.370000 (  1.377121)
match           4.400000   0.000000   4.400000 (  4.398849)
named capture   5.240000   0.010000   5.250000 (  5.243799)
look behind     1.430000   0.000000   1.430000 (  1.437286)
```

Comment: And +1 for explaining the requested and crazy approach.

Comment: I’m surprised how much slower the `match` is than the regex `[]`.

Comment: It's because `match` creates a MatchData object. The others would return an integer or simple string. Named-captures are costly too, but have the convenience of creating the local variable on the fly.

Comment: Holy wow... this is awesome and hugely informative. Thanks, Tin Man :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a lookbehind with an anchor, example:

```
(?<=^.{2}).{3}
```

will give you 345